# using MockK to mock retrofit interface returns null

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I'm using MockK as mock library for kotlin. I'm trying to mock the retrofit interface and then mock its response -> call the repository which should use the mocked interface and return the expected value. but for some reason it's always returning `null`

```
internal class TestClass {

  private val service: MyService = mockk(relaxed = true)
  private val repository: MyRepository = MyRepositoryImp(
    service = service
  )

  @Test
  fun test() = runBlocking {
    val expected = SOMETHING

    every { service.getRemoteData() } returns Response.success(SOMETHING)

    val result = repository.getRemoteData().first().data

    assertEquals(expected, result) //// result is null
  }
}
```

`MyService` is just a retrofit interface

```
internal interface MyService {

  @GET("123")
  suspend fun getRemoteData(): Response<SOMECLASS>

}
```

`MyRepositoryImp`

```
internal class MyRepositoryImp(
  private val service: MyService,
) : MyRepository {

  override fun getRemoteData(): Flow<SOMECLASS> {
    ....
            service.getRemoteData()
    ....
    )
  }

}
```

Anyone has any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To mock a suspend function using mockk, use `coEvery`, see the [doc](https://mockk.io/#coroutines)